# Getting only the first few characters when converting from PDF to image with ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, fonts, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick in PHP in order to convert the first page of a PDF file written in Japanese into an image file.

My problem is that only the first few characters are displayed in the image.

I tried everything. The PDF file is correct and the code doesn't return any error or warning.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(400,400);
$im->readimage($pdf_file.'[0]'); 
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->posterizeImage(1000,false);
$im->writeImage($image_file); 
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

The first line of the PDF file is :

委託者________（所在地：________）（以下「委託者」という）と受託者________（所在

But the image only displays:

委託者________（所在地：________）（以下「委託者

Comment: Maybe the information doesn't fit on the first page at that high resolution, try reducing the resolution (to say 144 dpi) to see if you get more.

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Post a link to your PDF file so others can test with it.

Comment: Practical question: why are you doing this through PHP-calling-imagemagick-calling-ghostscript, rather than using ghostscript direclty?